# Как задать доменное имя при cURL запросе по IP

Tags: php, curl, hosts

Допустим есть домен `blablabla.com`. Сам домен тестируется на хостинге, к которому не привязан посредством DNS. Допустим IP хостинга, на котором находится тестируемый домен: `255.255.255.15`

Если делаю запрос по IP адресу, то получаю стандартную заглушку хостинга.

Если прописываю в файле `hosts` (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`), строку

```
255.255.255.15   blablabla.com
```

то получаю нужный контент от сервера.

Каким образом получить контент через cURL (или каким либо другим способом) не внося изменений в `hosts`?

Иными словами, нужно обращаться к серверу по IP, но передавать правильное доменное имя.

Comment: ну если такой домен есть, то и прописывать ничего не надо - вы получите его ip через dns, другое дело, если такого домена нет, либо есть, но с другим (настоящим) ip, а вы хотите, чтобы вместо ошибки или настоящего сайта открывался ваш. Вас что конкретно интересует?

Comment: домен тестирую на другом хостинге, то есть домен не привязан к DSN хостинга, задачу я изложил более, чем понятно!

Comment: "_задачу я изложил более, чем понятно!_" - это вам только так кажется.

Comment: вы до google.com достучаться можете? а он разве привязан к вашему хостингу? у вас может быть нет этого домена? и поэтому вы и не можете ip его получить. Если есть, то как давно он есть? Может dns-записи еще не везде обновились, потому и не видите пока.

Comment: @valextt, Если при тестировании системы вам нужно задумываться о том, как лучше подменить IP, то ваша система плохо спроектирована. Такие вещи, как URL удаленных сервисов должны задаваться в **конфигурационном файле**.

Comment: Дмитрий, я же написал пример решения вопроса - можно прописать в файл C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts строчку "255.255.255.15   blablabla.com", но ищу другие варианты решения вопроса, чтоб не писать и не удалять строчку каждый раз из файла, когда проходит тестирование. Если у вас есть ответ на вопрос, милости прошу, не разводите флуд пожалуйста!

Comment: @valextt, а я вам уже сказал, что ваше решение -- костыль. Правильный подход -- передавать IP (доменное имя) удаленного сервиса через файл конфигурации. Решение на основе костылей писать не хочу. Возможно кто-то другой захочет.

Comment: Уважаемый Дмитрий, вы можете показать пример?

Comment: А вы пробовали **curl http:// 255.255.255.15**? Чем не устраивает? Если у вас доменное имя не привязано, это самый простой вариант

Comment: не привязан к DNS, но установлен на хостинге, если сделать просто curl http:// 255.255.255.15, то вылезет стандартная заглушка хостинга

Comment: @valextt а когда вы через hosts привязываете что-то другое получаете?

Comment: @Darth да, я написал комментарий ниже с результатами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cURL позволяет задавать заголовок `Host` при формировании запроса:

```
$ch = curl_init('255.255.255.15');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: blablabla.com'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo(curl_exec($ch));
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сорри, если неясно выразил мысль ...

Comment: У меня  по `https` протоколу не работает. Делаю запрос на ip адрес через постман и получаю ответ а пробую через  `curl` с таким же кодом и вылетает по таймауту с ошибкой `Failed to connect to 1.1.1.1 port 80: Connection timed out.`